# Screen resolution stuck at 1024x768 after updates and no nvidia driver works (22.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, 22.04

I've just updated my system as usual with

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

after a reboot my screen resolution was set to 1024x768 and only my primary screen is working.

Only the nouveau driver works fine, but I need the more powerful GPU driver from NVIDIA for other software, because the OpenSource one isn't powerful enough.

I literally tried almost every possible driver listed here

(525,515,510,390,470 (always the non-server nvidia package):
[image]

... but no one is working.

**what I tried already:**

- sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-510/jammy
- sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-dkms-510/jammy

and

- sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-525/jammy
- sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-dkms-525/jammy

and

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

nothing worked. I hate this moments so much with GNU/Linux.
I hope someone of you with more experience could share your ideas with me. of corse I did a reboot after every single change. in the meantime I did updates here and then. I'm almost giving up.

Comment: Phased updates sometimes cause Nvidia problems. Try sudo apt -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true upgrade

Comment: thanks, but it didn't helped :/ The system installes only a ~17 KB Update and after that I typed in sudo apt update but there were no updates available. I switched the current 470 driver to the 525 nvidia driver, rebooted and the problems are still there :( maybe another idea? :/

Comment: Something seems subtly broken in the selection of the default GPU -- used to be selecting settings/power/performance would set the default to the Nvidia, but no longer.  Running X (vs Wayland) xrandr --listproviders should show Nvidia and Intel, but their hybrid use seems reversed. (Intel should be the display "sink output"). This can be changed with __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <prg to run>  for an individual program, but looks like you need those env vars earlier in the setup, rc.local?  Had to change steam config to not use default GPU to get Nvidia.

Comment: I do not see that you are purging the driver between attempts to install the driver. Always a good idea to start with a clean slate.

Comment: chatgpt had the idead to try nvidia-smi to show me the nvidia version. This ist the Answer I'm receiving all the time:

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

I uninstalled really everthing like chatgpt told (sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-*), did an autoremove and installed one new 470 package (sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470)

I don't understand, why the system can not communicate with the drivers- it seems that it doesn't matter which driver :(